# How can there be instances of classes that cannot be instantiated?

Tags: python

I stumbled across the fact that `dict_keys` and `dict_values` cannot be instantiated by the user.

For example:

```
>>> d = {1:2}
>>> type(d.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>> type(d.keys())()
[...]
TypeError: cannot create 'dict_keys' instances
```

But if `dict_keys` instances cannot be created, how was `d.keys()` created?

Is there a way I could create a `dict_keys` instance in Python code?

Comment: In CPython dicts are implemented in C code. You can always have a look at the source code if you are interested how they are created exactly.

Comment: ***You*** can't create instances of it... `dict`s are built-in and implemented in C level. Obviously they can create such objects...

Comment: FWIW, the proper way to create such keys *would* be ``dict_keys(d)`` – which is exactly what ``d.keys()`` already does for you. There is no practical need to invest the effort to add another but less robust way to create ``dict_keys``.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a type in Python is just *one* way to create an instance. You may not be able to *call* `dict_keys`, but that doesn't preclude the implementation of `dict` from creating an instance further down in the implementation itself.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way I could create a `dict_keys` instance in Python code?

Comment: @actual_panda Yes. Call `d.keys()`...

Comment: You can do it via {}.keys()

Comment: I don't think so. It's not just a matter of calling `dict_keys`; you can't call `type.__call__` explicitly with `dict_keys` as its first argument, either. Strictly speaking, I don't think `dict_keys` is part of Python itself; it's just an implementation detail of CPython. Further, the documentation specifically mentions the existence of *callable types* in the [Standard Type Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), which implies the existence of non-callable types.

Comment: I am assuming you mean creating one directly, rather than getting one back from `dict.keys`. For example, one *can* create a `function` object without using `def`, by calling `types.FunctionType` directly with the appropriate code object and global namespace. Nothing like `dict_key` is exposed by the `types` module, suggesting it is not something you can create directly.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a trivial example of a class that "cannot be instantiated":

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, _fail=True) -> None:
        if _fail is True:
            raise TypeError(f"cannot create '{self.__class__.__name__}' instances")

class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def keys():
        return Bar(_fail=False)

foo = Foo()
bar = foo.keys()  # this works
bar = Bar()  # this fails
```

Now of course, you could say "this doesn't count: I could create an instance of `Bar` if I knew its inner workings beforehand. I'd simply need to add the `_fail=False` parameter". Well, surely you could also instantiate a `dict_keys` instance if you look  at the source code and figure out a way to bypass the exception being raised :-)

Comment: `b = object.__new__(Bar)`. Raising an exception in `Bar.__init__` doesn't prevent the class from being instantiated in the first place.

Comment: @chepner Fair enough, but that's not the point I was making. I simply tried to show to OP that there's nothing special about `dict_keys` not being instantiable - it's simply a design limitation, which can be bypassed if you dig deep enough and modify the necessary parts (as with your example).

Comment: Not necessarily. You *claiming* it can be bypassed does not make it true. All you are doing is demonstrating *an* obstacle to creating an instance of a class that can be used.